# Image overlays In iOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, image, opencv

I am making an app where user captures an Image, then edit it by adding overlay texts, line drawings etc.

The image can be saved and can be edited by using any other device(iOS or Android).

The problem is that I have managed to get the texts and lines to be drawn in different devices, but they are not placed perfectly. I have taken the ratios of the text's size to the main image's size.

Please suggest me some library or direct me towards any Vision library which can do this by analyzing the image.

Comment: Requests for libraries are off topic.  Asking how to do it yourself is on topic, but you've given no code and haven't been specific enough about what you want to give an answer.

Comment: I am requesting for library, I am asking for a suggestion of a library. As this is more of a theoretical question, I expect some theoretical responses. Thanks

Comment: Requests for library suggestions are off topic

Comment: okay, so is there any other Stackexchange site for it?

Answer (score 1):

Let's take iOS as an example. In that case, you have to display the original image in a UIImageView. Depending the on the aspect ratio of the image and the size+orientation of the device's display, the position and size of the image on the screen will vary. In short, you will have a mapping between the image coordinates and the screen coordinates, which you have to calculate when the image is displayed.
Now you can create and display the overlay according to this mapping, and when the user is done with editing, convert the locations back to image coordinates. Only then you can write the contents of the overlay to the original image.

If you find this too much work, you can use Adobe Creative SDK (formerly Aviary SDK) to do the hard work for you.